# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, html

I'm happy with some updates from my Website but I can't find out what I am doing wrong.

I getting this error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

```
{
    $successMSG = "";
    header("refresh:0;http://145.53.93.209/comments/user/update_profile_pic.php?
        id=$user->filter->userid"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
}
```

It does not detect the following code:

```
$user->filter->userid
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: `refresh:0;` redirects after 0 seconds, not 5, if you want 0 seconds you should be using a `header('Location: http://145....')` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with [curly braces while complex expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) are using.

```
header("refresh:0;http://145.53.93.209/comments/user/update_profile_pic.php?
id={$user->filter->userid}");        
// ^ --------------------^
```

Comment: Dear Pranav can you give me a example i don`t understand you ?

Comment: @JanJanMolendijk `$user->filter->userid` ===> `{$user->filter->userid}`